# Generating Artificial Test Clusters

Tags: testing, cluster-computing

Most authors generated their test clusters using Milligan's algorithm (well cited paper,Milligan, G.: An algorithm for creating artificial test clusters. Psychometric 50 (1985) 123–127). And A public domain implementation of this algorithm is available from Dave Dubin (Dubin, D.: clusgen.c. http://alexia.lis.uiuc.edu/ ̃dubin/ (1996)). However, this link is not available. Could you please tell me if there is any other implementation of this algorithm or other ways to generate artificial test clusters? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using MixSim in R or CARP in C which is considered to be some sort of a modern gold standard for assessing clustering. CARP appears to be more flexible. You can get the R package from CRAN, and the C package from [MLOSS](http://www.mloss.org/software/search/?searchterm=carp&post=)
Hope this helps!